# Speech recognition supported languages on WP8

Tags: speech-recognition, windows-phone-8

I tried Speech API example for Windows Phone 8. It is working good with English language, but when I switch emulator's language setting to Russian language, speech recognition broke.

On this code:

```
// Perform speech recognition.  
this.recoOperation = recognizer.RecognizeAsync();
var recoResult = await this.recoOperation;
```

It throws Exception:

**SPERR_WINRT_UNSUPPORTED_LANG** 0x800455BC The requested language is not supported.

So, It is means what Russian language is not supported with Speech Recognitiona API or I should change some additional settings to make it work?

Also I get this error for ja-JP and zh-HK languages.

Where can I find information about **really** supported languages?

Thanks.

Comment: Can i use speech recognition on an audio clip? To identify the content of the audio?

Comment: It seems, no. [SpeechRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer(v=vs.105).aspx) class have only `RecognizeAsync()` method without any parameters for audio stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried the same. I asked through Microsoft contacts. They say dictation grammar for remote recognition is not supported for any languages that you get this error for. You have to go with local recognition defined by Lists or SRGS grammar files for languages like Japanese, Chinese, Russian, etc.

Even if the language is installed, some languages will not support dictation remote recognition.

```
IReadOnlyCollection<SpeechRecognizerInformation> voices = InstalledSpeechRecognizers.All;
foreach (SpeechRecognizerInformation s in voices)
{
       Debug.WriteLine(s.Language);
}
```

The list of installed languages are:

```
en-US
de-DE
zh-TW
fr-FR
it-IT
ja-JP
pl-PL
pt-BR
ru-RU
en-IN
zh-CN
en-GB
es-MX
zh-HK
es-ES
```

Comment: The question is still not answered which is where can we programmatically retrieve the languages that work for remote dictation. Any ideas?

Comment: I would even like just a static list of languages that work with remote dictation so I don't have to spend so much time testing every language