# en-in language Speech recognition supported languages on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice, windows-phone-8-sdk

I tried Speech API example for Windows Phone 8. in my call phone 2 languages install en-GB and en-IN and my phone default language is en-in, when i tried with en-gb, it is working fine but when i tried with phone default language which is en-in, it is not working
it gives error , it throws exception.

On this code:

Perform speech recognition.

```
this.recoOperation = recognizer.RecognizeAsync();
var recoResult = await this.recoOperation;
It throws Exception:

**SPERR_WINRT_UNSUPPORTED_LANG 0x800455BC The requested language is not supported.**
```

So, It is means what Indian English is not supported with Speech Recognitiona API or I should change some additional settings to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech recognition supported languages on WP8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264903/speech-recognition-supported-languages-on-wp8)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation on Dev Center, this error code means “The requested language is not supported.” And this will happen on a new phone (or sometimes after you reset the phone) when the speech is activated, a language is chosen, but the language pack is not actually downloaded and installed on the phone. The user will have to go to phone settings to choose another speech language and then switch back again to see the message prompt for installing the language pack.

Answer (score 0):

Bing speech require english(us) language(or other supported language) to be enabled in your phone's language settings. After that you get a prompt to restart, which will make it work