# How many languages does Speech Recognition supports in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

When tried below code its throwing exception

```
SpeechRecognizerUI speechRecognition = new SpeechRecognizerUI();
SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await speechRecognition.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
```

The language which I tried is ru-RU(Russian). The error message is "The text associated with this error code could not be found.\r\n\r\nThe requested language is not supported."
In settings i enabled Russian for Speech even though i am getting this.

How many languages this SpeechRecognition API will support?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech recognition supported languages on WP8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264903/speech-recognition-supported-languages-on-wp8)

Answer (score 0):

To use speech recognition, you must set the ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION, ID_CAP_MICROPHONE, and ID_CAP_NETWORKING capabilities in the app manifest. If you do not set these capabilities, your app might not work correctly

In this site you can find details about what and where windows phone 8 features and services are available

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/basics/feature-and-service-availability

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Language support for Speech Recognition](http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsoft-doubles-language-support-windows-phone-8-doubles-speech-recognition-too) `Russian` does support the API.

For the exception just check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662934(v=vs.105).aspx) thread.

IF you still don't find out, you could see this thread [Problem with Speech API](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/42609054-43f3-4ba9-9650-77b781977c2e/problem-with-speech-api-on-wp8?forum=wpdevelop) which explains the same issue.

Hope it helps!